# create list based on values in two other lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose that I have two lists that look like this:

```
A = [(1,4), (5,2), (10, 8), (11, 3), (59, 14)]
B = [4, 2, 3, 4, 8, 14, 4, 2]
```

I want to create a new list called `C` based on list `A` and list `B` so that `C` looks like this:

```
C = [(1,4), (5,2), (11,3), (1,4), (10,8), (59,14), (1,4), (5,2)]
```

That is, I want to link each value in `B` with the first value in the corresponding tuple in `A` based on the second value in the tuple.

I think I can do this with a for loop as follows:

```
C  = []
    for tuple in A:
        for number in B:
            if number == tuple[1]:
                C.append(tuple)
```

but I don't think this will be very efficient for large lists.

**Question:** Is there a more efficient way of creating list `C`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
A = [(1,4), (5,2), (10, 8), (11, 3), (59, 14)]
B = [4, 2, 3, 4, 8, 14, 4, 2]

a = {t[1]: t for t in reversed(A)}  # reverse to guarantee first tuple for each key
# {14: (59, 14), 3: (11, 3), 8: (10, 8), 2: (5, 2), 4: (1, 4)}

C = [a[x] for x in B]
#[(1, 4), (5, 2), (11, 3), (1, 4), (10, 8), (59, 14), (1, 4), (5, 2)]
```

You build a mapping from second values to first `tuple` in `A` and use that in the comprehension. This ensures you iterate both `A` and `B` only once.

Comment: Or `reversed(A)` for a hundred times more readable alternative to `A[::-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict to map the second item in the tuple to the first, and then use the mapping to create `C`:

```
d = {b: a for a, b in A}
C = [(d[k], k) for k in B]
```

`C` would become:

```
[(1, 4), (5, 2), (11, 3), (1, 4), (10, 8), (59, 14), (1, 4), (5, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first create a dictionary of the first Array of tuple with key as the second value and value as the tuple. This is have **O(N)** time complexity. Now when you are looping it on the second array of numbers, then you can access dictionary with **O(1)** time complexity. So the total time complexity of the whole program would be **O(N)** + **O(M)** where N is the length of tuple, and M is length of the array

```
A = [(1,4), (5,2), (10, 8), (11, 3), (59, 14)]
B = [4, 2, 3, 4, 8, 14, 4, 2]

X = {}
for element in A:
    X[element[1]] = element

# X = {4: (1, 4), 2: (5, 2), 8: (10, 8), 3: (11, 3), 14: (59, 14)}
C = []
for element in B:
    C.append(X[element])

print(C)
# [(1, 4), (5, 2), (11, 3), (1, 4), (10, 8), (59, 14), (1, 4), (5, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

```
C = [(*[j[0] for j in A if j[1] == i], i) for i in B] 
# [(1, 4), (5, 2), (11, 3), (1, 4), (10, 8), (59, 14), (1, 4), (5, 2)]
```